# js const 配列メンバ変数を用意する方法が知りたい　Object.freezeの使い方がわからない

Tags: javascript

###### 質問内容

テトリスゲームの製作で回転したときのフォールキックパターンの配列のデータなのですがこの値は変更しないので`const`にしたいのですが以下の`///`コメント部内部のように参考サイト参考に実装したいのですが値が書き換えられてしまうので上手く実装出来ていません。クラスメンバ配列変数の場合どうやって実装するのでしょうか？

###### 質問内容

`///`コメント部内部の`this.fixRotatePosition`配列変数を`const`にして書き換え不能にする方法が知りたい。

###### 試したこと

参考サイトを参考に実装したのですが値が書き換えられてしまいます。

参考サイト：　https://web-engineer-wiki.com/javascript/const-object-array/

```js
"use strict"

/*#############################################################
# プレイヤー　管理クラス
###############################################################*/
class PlayerManager
{
    //回転時座標修正　I以外
    fixRotatePosition = 
    [
        [
            {x: -1,y:  0},
            {x: -1,y: -1},
            {x:  0,y: -2},
            {x: -1,y: -2}
        ],

        [
            {x:  1,y:  0},
            {x:  1,y: -1},
            {x:  0,y: -2},
            {x: 1, y:  2}
        ],

        
        [
            {x:  1,y:  0},
            {x:  1,y:  1},
            {x:  0,y: -2},
            {x: 1, y: -2}
        ],

        [
            {x:  -1,y:   0},
            {x:  -1,y:  -1},
            {x:   0,y:   2},
            {x:   1,y:  -2}
        ],            
    ]; 



    /*#########################################
    # コンストラクタ
    ###########################################*/
    constructor()
    {
        
        this.random = 0;        //乱数
        this.piece = [];        //ブロック
        this.position = {};     //座標
        this.rotateRadian = 0;  //回転数
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Object.freeze(this.fixRotatePosition);

        this.fixRotatePosition[0][0].x = 3;
        console.log(this.fixRotatePosition[0][0].x);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }


    /*#########################################
    # 初期化
    ###########################################*/
    Init()
    {
        const START_POSITION = {x: 4,y: 1}; //初期座標

        this.position = START_POSITION; //座標
        this.random = 1;
        this.piece = BitMap.getPiece(this.random);
        this.rotateRadian = 0;  //回転数



    }

    
    /*#########################################
    # Left 移動
    ###########################################*/
    LeftKey()
    {
        this.position.x += -1;
  
    }

    /*#########################################
    # Right 移動
    ###########################################*/
    RightKey()
    {
        this.position.x += 1;
    }
    
    /*#########################################
    # スペース　回転
    ###########################################*/
    SpaceKey()
    {
        this.rotateRadian += 1;

        if(this.rotateRadian > 3)
        {
            this.rotateRadian = 1;
        }

        this.Rotate(this.rotateRadian);
        
    }


    /*#########################################
    # 描画
    ###########################################*/
    Render() 
    {
        for(let i = 0; i < PIECE_HEIGHT; i++)
        {
            for(let j = 0; j < PIECE_WIDTH; j++)
            {
                if(this.piece[i][j] == 1)
                {
                    fill(BitMap.getPieceColor(this.random));
                    rect( (this.position.x + j) * CELL, (this.position.y + i ) * CELL,CELL,CELL);
                }
            }            
        }
    }
  
    
    
    /*#########################################
    # 当たり判定
    ###########################################*/
    Collision(stage)
    {
        
    }

    /*#########################################
    # 回転
    ###########################################*/
    Rotate(radian)
    {
        let rotate = new Array(4);
        rotate[0] = new Array(4).fill(0);
        rotate[1] = new Array(4).fill(0);
        rotate[2] = new Array(4).fill(0);
        rotate[3] = new Array(4).fill(0);

        for(let y = 0; y < PIECE_HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            for(let x = 0; x < PIECE_WIDTH; x++)
            {
                if(this.piece[y][x] == 1)
                {
                    let xx = (cos(PI / 2 * radian) * (x - 1.5)) + (-sin(PI / 2 * radian) * (y - 1.5));
                    let yy = (sin(PI / 2 * radian) * (x - 1.5)) + ( cos(PI / 2 * radian) * (y - 1.5));

                    rotate[Math.round((yy + 1.5))][Math.round((xx + 1.5))] = 1;
                }
            }    
        }

        this.piece = rotate.slice();    //描画配列にコピー


        
        RotateFix();



    }



    /*#########################################
    # 回転　位置修正
    ###########################################*/
    RotateFix()
    {
        let pos = Object.assign({},this.position);

        pos.x += -1;


    }




    /*#########################################
    # 計算
    ###########################################*/
    Update()
    {

    }


};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object.freeze()
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

> 浅い凍結とは
> Object.freeze(object) を呼び出した結果は、object の直属のプロパティにのみ適用され、object 上のみに対するその後のプロパティの追加、削除、値の再割り当て操作を禁止します。これらのプロパティの値がオブジェクトそのものであった場合、これらのオブジェクトは凍結されず、プロパティの追加、削除、値の再割り当て操作の対象になり得ます。

とのことですので、配列の配列を外からfreezeしても、1次元目の配列しか凍結されていないと推測します
配列の配列の場合は、外からfreezeしたうえで、さらに1次元目の要素全てをfreezeする必要があるはずです。